# Firebase for Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, firebase, firebase-authentication

The [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) from google looks promising and I was thinking if I could use it for user authentication in my Java EE project. The documentation looks great for Android, iOS and Web(Javascript). I want to know if the Android portion is applicable for Java EE too.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/

Answer (score 1):

No I Think The Admin Is For Java EE